# Dropdown control in PartialView populates but same control in other tab won't

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have a View that has bootstrap tabs, and in 2 of the tabs I have a PartialView, the PartialView is for Address and the other PartialView is for Contact.

The Address PartialView looks like this..

```
<script src="~/Scripts/Custom/Common/CommonControlsJS.js"></script>

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="txtAddress1" class="control-label col-md-2" id="lblAddress1">Line 1</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input id="txtAddress1" type="text" class="form-control max-size" name="address" placeholder="Line 1" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="txtAddress2" class="control-label col-md-2" id="lblAddress2">Line 2</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input id="txtAddress2" type="text" class="form-control max-size" placeholder="Line 2" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="txtCity" class="control-label col-md-2" id="lblCity">City</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input id="txtCity" type="text" class="form-control max-size" name="city" placeholder="City" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="txtState" class="control-label col-md-2" id="lblState">State</label>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input id="txtState" type="text" class="form-control" name="state" placeholder="State" />
        </div>
        <label for="txtZip" class="control-label col-md-2" id="lblZip">Zip/Postal</label>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input id="txtZip" type="text" class="form-control" name="zip" placeholder="Zip/Postal" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="acCountries" class="control-label col-md-2" id="lblCountry"><b>Country</b></label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <select id="acCountries" class="form-control" name="country"></select>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

and my Contact PartialView looks like this...

```
<script src="~/Scripts/Custom/Common/CommonControlsJS.js"></script>
<div class="form-horizontal">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="txtContactType">Contact&nbsp;Type:</label>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <input class="form-control fixed-form-control" id="ddContactType" placeholder="ContactType" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="txtContact">Contact:</label>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <input class="form-control fixed-form-control" id="txtContact" placeholder="Contact" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="txtPhone">Home:</label>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <input class="form-control fixed-form-control" id="txtPhone" placeholder="Home" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="txtWork">Work:</label>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <input class="form-control fixed-form-control" id="txtWork" placeholder="Work" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="txtFax">Fax:</label>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <input class="form-control fixed-form-control" id="txtFax" placeholder="Fax" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="txtMobile">Mobile:</label>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <input class="form-control fixed-form-control" id="txtMobile" placeholder="Mobile" />
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

In the Address PartialView I have a dropdown control called acCountries, this gets populated from my CommonControlsJS file and this is the code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    CommonControlLibrary.GetCountries();
});

var CommonControlLibrary = {
    GetCountries: function () {
        var self = this;
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Common/GetCountries?id=" + 21,
            dataType: "JSON",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                self.ShowCountries(data);
            }
        });
    },
    ShowCountries: function (countryData) {
        $("#acCountries").kendoDropDownList({
            dataSource: countryData,
            dataTextField: "dictionaryName",
            dataValueField: "dictionaryItemID",
            animation: false,
            optionLabel: {
                dictionaryName: "-- Select Country --",
                dictionaryItemID: "0"
            }
        })
    }
}
```

I have a Manufacturer tab and a Dealer Tab, each of these tabs holds an Address PartialView and a Contact PartialView, the issue I am running into is that the Address PartialView acCountries dropdown populates, but the Address PartialView in the Dealer tab acCountries dropdown will not populate and I have no idea why.

Since this is happening in the Address PartialView, I know I am going to run into this issue with the Contact PartialView because I'll be adding a dropdown in there for Contact Type.

What would be the cause of one Address PartialView acCountries dropdown populate, but not the second Address PartialView acCountries dropdown not populate?

**EDIT**

What it looks like using a class instead of an id

[image: Instead of using id]

Comment: If you duplicating those partials, then you have duplicate `id` attributes which is invalid html (use class names instead)

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I tried as you suggested and it did work. However, I just made an edit to my question and added a screenshot based on your suggestion and now the layout is out of whack. Any idea's on why this is happening or maybe another way to do this?

Comment: I assume that is just a styling issue. But its hard to understand what you trying to do here. Many of you controls do not even have name attributes, you not binding to a model, it could never bind correctly to a model when you submit etc. You have tagged this asp.net-mvc yet everything your doing is anti mvc. And why are you populating a dropdownlist using ajax anyway instead of passing the values to the view in the first place?

Comment: Yes probably just a styling issue..You bring up a lot of good questions. When the project was started it was settled that we would not use Razor at all. We use JQuery extensively in this project. I did tag this in mvc because it is an mvc project, but I can see where you are coming from, maybe I shouldnt have tagged this with MVC, but thats besides the point. I wouldn't really agree that the approach is anti mvc, we are still using the MVC, just not using Razor. For your last question, we are using KendoUI and like being difficult and not using razor ;)

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I fixed the styling issue...If you want to add your comment as the answer than please do because it was correct

Comment: Well its anti-mvc in that you are throwing away all the features of mvc (strong typed model binding, validation etc) that its designed for, and writing twice as much code in doing so :)